# Systemd service, Working Directory not change the directory

Tags: 18.04, services, systemd

I created this script:

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser
ExecStart=/somescript.sh

Restart=always
RestartSec=10

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=autodeploy

Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1494

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I'm running it, it says:

```
Process: 8986 ExecStart=/somescript.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I understood that this message means the script won't found...
Why Working Directory not working for me?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a `/` in front of `somescript.sh`. I don't suppose you put `somescript.sh` in the root of the filesystem?

Comment: I put it inside `/home/someuser`. It's needs to run in this directory. I tried to do it with `WorkingDirectory` but it can't find the script.

Comment: If you put it in `/home/someuser`, then tell the system that it is there. Look closely at `ExecStart=/somescript.sh`: where does this say the script is? (Hint: where is `/home` located?)

Comment: I need the service to run it from the original directory *only* (`/home/someuser/somescript.sh` will not work for me), I tried to use `WorkingDirectory` to change the directory before executing it. Do you have some idea how can I do it?

Comment: I really don't get what you want? This works: `ExecStart=/home/someuser/somescript.sh` and is the way to do it; otherwise there might be another error not related to the service.

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong when you set the `WorkingDirectory` and use the full  path to the script?

Comment: Adding to @Rinzwind: for instance, the script could be [lacking execute permission or missing its shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The systemd [`WorkingDirectory=` setting](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) defines on which directory the service will be launched, same as when you use `cd` to change a directory when you're working in the shell.

That doesn't mean that all the other paths (including that from `ExecStart=`) will now be relative to it, so you still need to fully specify the path to your script in that directive:

```
ExecStart=/home/someuser/somescript.sh
```

Perhaps you were thinking of the [`RootDirectory=` directive](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#RootDirectory=) instead? That directory uses the `chroot` command to switch the root of the filesystem seen by the process by the directory you specify, so from your use of `/` for the location of the script, that looks like maybe what you wanted... However, using `RootDirectory=` requires that you have a system image, with binaries and libraries under it. Like, you need to have a `/bin/sh` to run your shell script, and a `/lib` with a libc, etc. Typically you can't just use `RootDirectory=` to just about any directory that you like...

So my advice here in order to fix the issue you're seeing is to just update the `ExecStart=` to list the full path to your script.

Comment: But what does `ExecStart=./somescript.sh` do?

Answer (score 30):

I found relative paths work, but you're using an **absolute** path for ExecStart.  It isn't looking for `/home/someuser/somescript.sh`, it's looking for ***/***`somescript.sh` which is looking for the file under the root directory.  That simply isn't where the file is, so it fails.

You can probably get it working by changing `ExecStart=somescript.sh`

---

From: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

> For each of the specified commands, the first argument must be either an absolute path to an executable or a simple file name without any slashes.

Comment: Hilariously, this is actually the correct answer to the question. While @filbranden's answer is excellent, it's not actually the answer to the question. Have an upvote infernalrapture, you deserve it.

Comment: `./` did not work for me in Debian Bullseye

Comment: Relative paths *do not* work for the binary that Systemd runs. However, that binary, once running, can do whatever it wants with the arguments that are passed to it, like treat them as relative paths.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CameronTacklind and @forresthopkinsa. I corrected this answer by removing `./` from ExecStart and adding a quote from documentation and a link to the reference. ☮️❤️

Comment: If you don't use an absolute path, then it will search in a at-compiled-time predefined path (which you can query with `systemd-path search-binaries-default`). So even if you set `Environment=PATH=...`, if the command is not in any of the predefined directories, systemd will not found it. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines

Answer (score 4):

This also works:

```ini
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c './somescript.sh'
```